# Prefix routing in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

Routing in cakephp 2.x:

- in core.php : `Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin', 'user'));`
- in `UsersController` I create a method for admin and other for user.  Example:

  `public function admin_edit()`
  `public function user_edit()`
- in `Views` I create a directory for admin and other for user. Example:

  `Views/Users/admin/edit.ctp`
  `Views/Users/user/edit.ctp`
- Finally, the routes:

  For admin : `www.sitio.com/users/**admin**/edit`
  For user : `www.sitio.com/users/**user**/edit`

How would I implement the same in CakePHP 3? I read this documentation, but I don't understand: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Your usage of `prefix` isn't standard - in 3.x you wouldn't use the routing feature "prefix" - all your routes would probably be defined in the `/` scope defining `'prefix' => x` in each route definition.